# how to set different background images in different slides by apache poi XSLF

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I'm using apache poi to generate ppt. i can set all the background of slides by one same image, i want know how to set different background images in different slides .

Comment: Yes you can.  https://poi.apache.org/slideshow/quick-guide.html

Comment: @Sid thanks for your help.but i can't find the information I need from XSLF Cookbook.